# Check if string does not contain strings of an array of string in C# in query from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, arrays, string, entity-framework, contains

I tried to get a special count where I want to remove results where the userKeysActionsArray is a string that contains integer like this way (JSON array) : [88254,8547,8569]

But when I tried to remove with a contains method and the NOT operator, I couldn't get the right number I expected.

I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Thanks a lot for your help.

```
int count;

var query = (from a in _db.ApplicationSet
             from h in a.ApplicationApprobationStatusHistorySet
             from u in a.Mission.MissionUserSet
             where a.Mission.isDeleted == false
                && a.Mission.isArchived == false
                && a.isRefused == false
                && a.ApplicationApprobationStatus.shortCode == "APPLICATION_APPROBATION_STATUS_LM_WAITING"
                && u.userKey == ContextUser.id
                && h.ApplicationApprobationStatus.shortCode == "APPLICATION_APPROBATION_STATUS_LM_WAITING" && h.isDeleted == false
              orderby a.applicationDate
              select new ApplicationCandidateListing
              {
                  applicationKey = a.id,
                  missionKey = a.Mission.id,
                  candidateKey = a.Candidate.id,
                  statusKey = a.ApplicationStatus.id,
                  clientKey = a.Mission.Client.id,
                  candidateFirstName = a.Candidate.firstName,
                  candidateLastName = a.Candidate.lastName,
                  clientLabel = a.Mission.Client.name,
                  statusLabel = a.ApplicationStatus.label,
                  missionLabel = a.Mission.label,
                  applicationDate = a.applicationDate,
                  isCVreserveList = a.isCVreserveList,
                  isCVviewed = a.isCVviewed,
                  refuseDate = a.refuseDate,
                  isShortListed = a.isShortListed,
                  candidateGroupShortcode = a.Candidate.CandidateGroup.shortCode,
                  approbationStatusIcons = a.ApplicationApprobationStatus.iconCSS,
                  approbationStatusShortCode = a.ApplicationApprobationStatus.shortCode,
                  isInternal = a.Candidate.isInternal,
                  lineManagerKey = ContextUser.id,
                  userKeysActionsArray = h.userKeysActionsArray,
                  commentCount = a.ApplicationCommentSet.Where(ac => ac.isPrivateLineManager != true).Count()
              }).Distinct();

string chance1 = "[" + ContextUser.id.ToString() + "]";
string chance2 = "[" + ContextUser.id.ToString() + ",";
string chance3 = "," + ContextUser.id.ToString() + ",";
string chance4 = "," + ContextUser.id.ToString() + "]";

var values = new[] { chance1, chance2, chance3, chance4 };
query.Where(q => !(values.Any(q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains)));  

count = query.Count();

return count;
```

Comment: I believe Contains is a method that requires an input parameter, so try changing your second last line from `q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains` to `q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(input value)`

Comment: You are missing affectation to the count variable, is that a typo ?

Comment: @ArwynFr yes sorry typo error :-) will update the post. Thanks

Comment: @Scopperloit I don't know how to change it to test the 4 possibilities.Like this ?  `query.Where(q => !((q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance1) && q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance2) && q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance3) && q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance4))));     `

Comment: Is each chance an array or a single string?

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani a single string because there could be 4 possibilities to be part of this string userKeysActionsArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as below -

```
query.Where(q => !(
(q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance1) ||
q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance2) || 
q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance3) || 
q.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(chance4))));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accumulate where conditions on the query in a foreach:

```
var query = // redacted

string chance1 = "[" + ContextUser.id.ToString() + "]";
string chance2 = "[" + ContextUser.id.ToString() + ",";
string chance3 = "," + ContextUser.id.ToString() + ",";
string chance4 = "," + ContextUser.id.ToString() + "]";

var values = new[] { chance1, chance2, chance3, chance4 };
foreach(var value in values)
{
    query = query.Where(a => !a.userKeysActionsArray?.Contains(value) ?? true);
}
return query.Count();
```

Comment: I will try this, could it be possible that the fact that the string "userKeysActionsArray" could be null that it will cause troubles?

Comment: This is what I would have done as well, `foreach` is your friend here. If you're worried about NullReferenceExceptions, always check for null first in boolean expressions. They always evaluate from left to right. Try `query.Where(a => a.userKeysActionsArray != null && !a.userKeysActionsArray.Contains(value));`

Comment: I've added a null-conditional operator and a null-coalescing operator to handle the null case